# Load Duplicate RDF triples into Apache Jena Fuseki

Tags: rdf, apache-jena

I am wondering if there is a way to initiate Apache Jean Fueseki server to accept log duplicate triples. see https://jena.apache.org/documentation/serving_data/

Right now I'm starting Fuseki with the following command

```
 ./fuseki-server --update --mem /ds
```

Then I'm loading in xml/rdf files using the post tool that comes with Fuseki, like so:

```
./s-post http://localhost:3030/ds/data default ~/Desktop/scta/commentaries/pp-projectdata.rdf
```

The file `pp-projectdata.rdf` sometimes contains identical triples, but I want these duplicates to be loaded so I can count the number of instances of this triple.

Answer (score 5):

Duplicate triples are not a part of the RDF data model and as such any RDF processor will typically silently ignore them.

From the [RDF 1.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf11-concepts/#data-model) specification:

> The core structure of the abstract syntax is a set of triples, each
>   consisting of a subject, a predicate and an object. A set of such
>   triples is called an RDF graph.

Set is used in the mathematical sense i.e. no duplicates.

More specifically the [RDF XML 1.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-syntax-grammar/#section-Data-Model) specification says the following:

> Software transforming RDF/XML into a representation of a graph may
>   eliminate duplicate predicate arcs.

i.e. duplicate triples may be ignored/discarded

So Fuseki (or any other RDF processing system) is explicitly permitted to discard duplicates